# Windows server is not building docker image

Tags: windows, docker, jenkins

I have a Jenkins job that is running on a Windows Server node with Docker installed.  The docker install path is `C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\`

I have the following command in my Jenkinsfile

`bat "'C:\\Program Files\\Docker\\Docker\\resources\\bin\\docker' build -t face-recognition-server ."`

However I get the following error on the [build log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHLXC.jpg)

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: You should post the entire build log.

Comment: I have added, please check it @ChrisMaggiulli

Comment: You need to use single quotes for the bat '' command and double quotes on the path.  I posted the answer. If it works for you please accept it as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Try to reverse the quotation characters. Wrap the command in single quotes and the path in double quotes.  The batch script is treating the single quote as part of the path instead of resolving it as a reserved character

```
bat '"C:\\Program Files\\Docker\\Docker\\resources\\bin\\docker" build -t face-recognition-server .'
```

> Additionally if you don't need to use Groovy's String Interpolation you should be using single quotes for Strings anyway